# using System.Speech.Synthesis with Windows10 universal app (XAML-C#)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, volume, speechsynthesizer

I tried to use the SpeechSynthesizer from System.Speech.Synthesis because it seems more comprehensive than the one I used before (Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis) : I want to be able to set the volume, the gender of the voice, ... Besides, the french prononciation has some bugs, so I wanted to check if System.Speech was better.

I added the reference, but the Build gives this error and I can't fix it :

```
Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary.
```

Comment: Hey, i work on the team that built the SpeechSynthesis API, You should be able to find a voice available for both male and female (see SpeechSynthesis.AllVoices for an enumeration of them, should be one for each of the supported speech languages installed). And if you use a MediaElement to play it back, there's a Volume property you can change to control it. Are those not doing what you need?

Comment: I browsed the available voices. In french, there's only one voice. I was looking for a kid's voice, since it is an application for very small children. For the volume, I will look on the MediaElement, thanks.

Comment: But much more important : I found many prononciation bugs with the french voice (when saying 70 for example). Moreover, I need to use a phonetic alphabet to be able to prononce sounds which don't exist in french language. For example, when I need to say "BA", I must write "bas" because this word exists in french. But I am unable to say BI : it will say "B. I.". Worse : when you say something that correspond to an abreviation, it says the whole expression : "AA" is not said as "A" but as "Alcooliques anonymes".

Comment: hm, there's definitely supposed to be two voices showing up for each language, I'll check when I get into work. But there isn't a childlike one, unfortunately. On the subject of pronunciation, you probably want to look into using SSML, because you can provide pronunciation guides there and should be able to tell it exactly what you want using the [phoneme element](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.1.10).

Comment: The phoneme element looks very interesting indeed. Well, I'll try to understand how it works. Thanks !

Comment: We've got a brief example of it in use if you open the [Speech Reco and Synthesis](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) sample from GitHub. Scenario 2 uses SSML, and uses the phoneme element to construct a word that can be pronounced a particular way with any language (and it should show both the male and female voice in the dropdown too, i'll poke into that a bit more, it's odd you're only seeing one.)

Comment: Looks powerfull !!! My first tests are encouraging. I dive in it without further delay. Thank you !

Comment: I must have made an error in the link sentence when I was looking for the french languages, because with SSML, I can have the two voices.

Comment: But I found something wrong : when I put "za ze zi zo zy" in the phoneme element, the z is said [z]. But if I put "za" (or other) alone, it says [r] or [ch] or [w] (depending of the voyel), but never [z]. I also tried &#x7a; , &#x290; , &#x291; and &#x292; which are not better. How can you play the sound [z] alone ? And I have the same kind of problem with "ha" (h aspiré).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to use the .NET API System.Speech.Synthesis in a WinRT app, without creating an app that will wind up failing the WACK tests for submission.

Many of the .NET namespaces haven't been projected into WinRT. In particular, System.Speech.* since there's already Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis and Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition, which were brought over from the windows phone API namespaces instead, and should be functionally complete for the majority of purposes.

Only old .NET APIs that are part of the [.NETCore profile](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) have been projected to WinRT.

Comment: It's a pity, because the samples you can find in the forums and tutorials almost always talk about System.Speech, which demonstrates that this is the favorite library for most developpers.

Comment: System.speech has been around longer, but it's based on older versions of the tech. Windows.Media is basically the same code base, but with a lot of improvements and support behind it, it just started with the phones version of the API. But if there's a feature that you want that has been left out, let me know, I'll make sure the team has a work item to track it.