# Unable to use System.Speech.Recognition namespace in a Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, uwp, msdn, speech-to-text

I would like to use the SpeechRecognizer class from the System.Speech.Recognition namespace in a Universal Windows App. It has more events and more other features than SpeechRecognizer defined in Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.

However, when I reference System.Speech.dll, for access to System.Speech.Recognition, I am getting error "Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary".

Is there a workaround to this or are classes defined in System.Speech.Recognition such as SpeechRecognizer and SpeechRecognitionEngine not meant to be used in Universal Windows Apps?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using System.Speech.Synthesis with Windows10 universal app (XAML-C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376192/using-system-speech-synthesis-with-windows10-universal-app-xaml-c)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in UWP apps. ([using System.Speech.Synthesis with Windows10 universal app (XAML-C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376192/using-system-speech-synthesis-with-windows10-universal-app-xaml-c))  What feature or event you are looking for exactly?

Comment: Well, the 3 events of Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer, which are HypothesisGenerated, RecognitionQualityDegrading and StateChanged are probably all you need as a bare minimum, but I can see where AudioSignalProblemOccurred, RecognizerUpdateReached could be useful.

Also, I like System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine which has a constructor that accepts a .wav file and also has a lot of other good features. I don't see a class equivalent in Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition. Am I wrong in thinking that Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition is more limited?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognitionaudioproblem.aspx

Comment: I found that for AudioSignalProblemOccurred, there are these enums, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognitionaudioproblem.aspx. As for loading and unloading grammar, I guess we can do that by adding or removing constraints from constraints list.  From my personal experience, I feel UWP is limited in terms of File and System accesses. Other than that I think it should be providing with all the features we need.