# Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml

I tried using `System.Speech.Systhesis` reference in uwp application in **Visual Studio 2019** but it didnt work,it shows error as:

> Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.MarshalByRefObject in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary.

I updated nuget package to **version 6.2.10** but this also didn't work out.What an be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

System.Speech.Systhesis is not Supported in UWP. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987041/unable-to-use-system-speech-recognition-namespace-in-a-universal-windows-app) for possible help.